# Maestro detalle en Angular 8

Tags: angular8, component

tengo que realizar el típico maestro/detalle  con Angular 8, y no se que componentes crear. 
Tengo un servicio que me trae N objetos Titulo:String, Detalle:string (Como si fueran noticias de un un diario).
Tengo que listar los títulos primero y después mostrar el detalle del titulo al que se le haga clic; se programar la comunicación entre componentes, pero no se si al hacer clic debo llamar a otra pagina (rutear), si debo ocultar todos los títulos y mostrar el detalle? 
Espero se haya entendido, gracias

Comment: Debes utilizar Angular routinng, aquí lo explican bien: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/introduccion-sistema-routing-angular.html Si después de intentarlo sigues sin conseguirlo añade el código que utilizaste y podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Revisa como hacer el archivo de **app.routes.ts**, después de eso podrías revisar como hacer **children** a los componentes. De esa manera puedes hacer un componentes para hacer la carga rápida de los títulos y dando clic, mandas a llamar otro modulo que te muestre todo el contenido.

Comment: Ok, si voy a hacer eso, pero cargando otro componente no usando el mismo del listado no?